# Oracle and entity framework in visual studio

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have installed all of the oracle software and databases and so on to work with .Net and Visual Studio 2010. There is a tutorial on the oracle website that describes how to work with the entity framework and oracle, yet.. when I am going through the entity data model wizard in visual studio 2010, I get to "choose your data connection", and the only thing there is "ApplicationServices". Yet in the tutorial on oracles website, there is an option for the oracle database? My oracle database is working and viewable from the server explorer... I have tried to edit web.config to add some kind of entry but that seems to have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install an EF provider for Oracle first? Oracle has [a beta provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html), and there are third-party providers (e.g., from Devart and others) as well.